# If $G$ is a $k$-regular graph with $ m $ vertices and $k$ is odd, show that $k\mid m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For now the only thing I am certain of is that the value of $m$ is even.
But I don't have a clue on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the cube graph (which is a $3$-regular graph on $8$ vertices) be a counterexample?

Comment: Well the problem is from my text book, I am not even sure what to do with it because I also thing that it isn't always possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly false. For instance, the complete graph on four vertices is 3-regular, yet $3 \nmid 4$. Or take the graph of the cube, a 3-regular graph on 8 vertices. Or the Petersen graph, a 3-regular graph on 10 vertices.

However, $m$ is more typically used for the number of edges (and $n$ is the number of vertices). It's true that $k$ divides the number of edges—your observation that $n$ is even is most of the way there.